# Dual Mosfet as a hard latch rather than soft?

Tags: mosfet, latch

I have built and tested the below circuit and it works well as a soft latch with a toggle function from the momentary switch.[image: Soft latch circuit]

How would I modify this circuit to latch once and not reset until either power is removed or a separate reset switch is pressed? Am I over complicating this?

Comment: Isn't it already the case that once latched, till power is removed, the latch does not get reset?

Comment: No. It is push on push off.

Comment: Yes, I understand your question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push on the switch once, the NMOS is turned ON and it discharges the capacitor C1. When the switch is pushed once more, the NMOS is turned OFF and the capacitor C1 gets charged to 12V. So, if you want to remove the latch reset functionality, you can prevent C1 from getting discharged when NMOS turns ON. Here is an idea.

[image]

Infact, may be you can even remove the capacitor and do something like the following

[image]

Be sure to try it out before you fabricate your board or have options on the board to revert back if it is not working as expected.

Comment: Thankyou. The first solution with the cap works perfectly.

Comment: The second solution doesn't work at all. It just dimly lights the LED when the momentary button is closed.

Comment: In the second solution, did you make R2 100ohm as indicated in the circuit? I am assuming you used 100k which is why it did not work.

Comment: You assume correct! Thanks for catching that. I clearly didn't pay enough attention.